# How to tune parameters for Time Series Analysis, when forecasting is only dominated by one feature and error is not getting reduced?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, feature-extraction, hyperparameter

I am trying to predict time series based on 150 features. When I plot correlation of these features, I am getting 20 features with more or less importance but every model I use, it is completely dominated by only one feature which is competently in sync with predicted output but not actual output . Please refer to the image below.

[image: TIme Series Forecast by tree classifier]

The green line is prediction which is completely in sync with one of the feature.And for every valley in actual output, I am getting 2 valleys in predicted output. No model is able to generalize this. Is it the case of bad data for model?

Comment: Have you tried dropping that overly important column and check what you get? Which model(s) have you tried? from the plot is visible that this has a seasonal, weekly, monthly trends, have you accounted for that also? Also why is everyone it's bouncing back from zero? That's a very steep change actually and your model is trying to do it's best

Comment: After dropping that overly important feature, I get  noise like prediction which has nothing to do with actual output. Currenlty i am using XGboost and tree ensemble to forecast the series.

Comment: Try using prophet as xgboost won't capture seasonal effects and all

Comment: I wonder if an rrn would perform well because the data seems to repeat in cycles

Answer (score 1):

The current method of XGboost and tree ensemble appears to not be closely modeling the actual times-series pattern. It might be better to use times-series-centric algorithms like AutoRegressive Integrated Moving Average (ARIMA) or Long Short Term Memory (LSTM).